# Have I permanently lost my Pokemon go account?

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I login to original. Want me to start over. Level 18

Comment: It's a glitch. Contact Niantic support ASAP. There's reports of accounts resetting. **DO NOT** go past the starter selection. Close as soon as Prof. Willow's dialog finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a glitch on the server's side that causes users' progress to reset as of the 0.31.0 (Android)/1.1.0 (iOS) update.
Personally, it hasn't happened to me, but there have been reports of this happening.

Currently, official sources ask you to:

> Should you have your progress reset, as this is a known glitch, **DO NOT** go the your Starter Pokemon selection. As soon as Willow finishes his dialog (or if you haven't finished it yet), **close the app** and contact Niantic Support ASAP for them to look at your account and rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after the update. Go onto your safari/chrome etc and check that you are signed into the google account you want to be. Then go on Pokemon Go and move through catching a Pokemon and creating a nickname. (Note: your old nickname is still taken) when you're through to get into settings log out and sign back into your old account. It should all be there!